# Как правильно вывести html в php-коде?

Tags: php, html

Есть у меня страничка с выбором даты. Дата через post передаётся и делается выборка данных по этой дате.
Пытаюсь всё это дело правильно обернуть в html, чтобы каждая таблица была отдельно, но где-то накосячил. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
<div class="main-content-inner">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <form method="post" name="delivery_date" action="">
                        <input class="form-control" type="date" name="delivery_date" value="" id="example-date-input"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs mb-3">Найти</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- table primary start -->
                    <div>
                    <?php
                    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); // Включаем вывод всех ошибок
                    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
                    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
                    require_once('db.php');

                    if(isset($_POST['delivery_date']))
                    {
                        $form_date = $_POST['delivery_date'];
                        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE delivery_date='$form_date' AND delivery=1";
                        $result = mysqli_query($link, $SQL);


                        while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            echo '<div class="col-md-6 mt-5">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="header-title">Заявка №<?=$res[\'id\']?></h4>
                                <ul class="list-group">
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><?=$res[\'name\']?></li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><?=$res[\'surname\']?></li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><?=$res[\'second_name\']?></li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><?=$res[\'phone\']?></li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><?=$res[\'birth_date\']?></li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><?=$res[\'birth_place\']?></li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><?=$res[\'citizenship\']?></li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><?=$res[\'doc\']?></li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><?=$res[\'doc_id\']?></li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><?=$res[\'doc_publish\']?></li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><?=$res[\'doc_date\']?></li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><?=$res[\'term\']?></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div> ';


                        }
                    }
                ?>
```

Как видите, я пытаюсь заполнить таблицу значениями. Мне нужно, чтобы во-первых: она заполнялась и корректно отображалась на странице, а во-вторых: чтобы за ней строилась вторая таблица с другим id но за ту же дату. 
Сейчас это выглядит так :(
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Сам разобрался.
Делаем отдельный файл и объявляем в нём функцию.

```
function get_printed_users()

    {

        global $link;
        if (isset($_POST['delivery_date'])) {
            $form_date = $_POST['delivery_date'];
            $SQL = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE delivery_date='$form_date' AND delivery=1";
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $SQL);
            $users = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            return $users;
        } else {

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE delivery = '1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25";
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
            $users = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            return $users;
        }
    }
```

Затем выводим всё через цикл.

```
<form method="post" name="delivery_date" action="">
<input class="form-control" type="date" name="delivery_date" value="" id="example-date-input"> 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs mb-3">Найти</button>
</form>
<?php
$post = get_printed_users();
 ?>
<?php foreach ($post as $users): ?>
<li class="list-group-item">Имя: <?=htmlspecialchars($users['name'], ENT_QUOTES)?></li>
<li class="list-group-item">Фамилия: <?=htmlspecialchars($users['surname'], ENT_QUOTES)?></li>
<li class="list-group-item">Отчество: <?=htmlspecialchars($users['second_name'], ENT_QUOTES)?></li>
<li class="list-group-item">Телефон: <?=htmlspecialchars($users['phone'], ENT_QUOTES)?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: интересно, что htmlspecialchars со всеми ненужными прибамбасами старательно вырисовываем, аж язычок высунув от усердия, а на sql инъекции вообще никакого внимания не обращаем

Comment: @Ипатьев ну что вы такой злой всегда :(
Этот код будет использоваться кроме меня ещё 2 людьми, к тому же доступ только через авторизацию. Я знаю про экранирование спецсимволов, но в этом пока не было необходимости просто.

Comment: я не злой, я просто удивляюсь. И экранирование спецсимволов к защите от sql инъекций не имеет ни малейшего отношения. Плюс про "не было необходимости" - это ты очень смешно сказал.

Comment: @Ипатьев, ну хоть от спагетти-кода ушёл. Уже прогресс